# Angularjs : Date type in angularjs input using ng-model returns undifined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello guys i have some issue using date type and ng-model together. in my index.html i have the input field like this :

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" id="date" ng-model="myData.date" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myExample()">Submit</button>
```

and my controller :

```
$scope.myExample = function() {
    console.debug('date : ', $scope.myData.date);
}
```

in my console i get the log "date : undefined"

what seems to be the problem why i'm having undefined value? thanks

by the way im using "bootstrap-datepicker"

Comment: have you selected a date and clicked enter. because it is working fine in my browser.

Comment: yes selected a date already. but when i click the btn its always undefined

Comment: are you using contoller as syntax?

Comment: yes. when i try to change the type to text i get the date but its not in a date format

Comment: are you using any datepicker, how can you get a date in text box, unless if you use a picker.

Comment: yes im using bootstrap-datepicker 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

and my js is like this $('#date').datepicker()

Answer (score 1):

You have to init your `myData` object

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {}; //Create the object 
  $scope.myExample = function() {
    console.log('date : ', $scope.myData.date);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input class="form-control" type="date" id="date" ng-model="myData.date" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myExample()">Submit</button>

</div>
```

Comment: hmm.. what datepicker u using?

Comment: I just copied your code, I am not using any external library. This is the default datepicker

Comment: so i think the problem is with my date picker. because i try ur suggest but still getting undefined data

Comment: And what is saved in $scope.myData ? Is that undefined also ?

Comment: yhup undefined but when i change type to text it gives a string date format

Comment: And which angular version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be passing the date value through your function.

This is how I have achieved this.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="date" ng-model="myData.date" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myExample(myData.date)">Submit</button>
<script>

  angular.module("myApp",[])
  .controller("myController",function($scope){
    $scope.myExample = function(date) {
      console.log(date);
    alert(date);
}

  })
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

You can also use date filter available in angularjs. See documentation here
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

Here is the required solution using **bootstrap-datepicker**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {}
    $scope.myData.date = new Date();
    $scope.myExample = function() {
     console.debug('date : ', $scope.myData.date);
      console.log('date : ', $scope.myData.date);
    }

});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>



<body>
<script>
$('#date').datepicker() 
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input class="form-control" type="date" id="date" ng-model="myData.date" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myExample()">Submit</button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/faD3f6mPlvvBR0UAFJMF?p=preview)

Comment: @Arnold, please check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to insert a placeholder attribute into the input tag, whose value is e.g.:

**placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"** (cause this works for me as well: placeholder="dd.MM.yyyy")

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" id="date" ng-model="myData.date" placeholder="dd.MM.yyyy" />
```

After that the ng-model processed it correctly and stored the value. In fact, in the documentation it is mentioned in the example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D